# Math Graph Symbols, Characters, or Glyphs in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to qualitatively describe an equation and would like to do so by using little pictures of the functions involved.

Therefore, I am looking for glyphs or a way of drawing cute little pictures of a sine wave, a gaussian, a logistic (or sigmoid) function, and a step function.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot these functions in a separate document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
    \draw plot [domain=0:2*pi](\x, {sin(\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would use a naming scheme like `img_sin.tex`. Then you can include them easily as:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\splot[1]{\includegraphics{img_#1}}

\begin{document}

The sinus looks like \splot{sin}.

\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Of course you can make the plots as fancy as you like.

Note that I chose a fixed scaling factor of `0.1` which looked good for me. It might be possible to scale the image to the current font height on inclusion, but I'm not sure how to do that.